# Recalcular valor al cambiar input type=range

Tags: javascript, html5

Requiero de su ayuda para solucionar un problema.

Tengo un input type range el cual a medida que se cambia coloca el valor en un output, hasta aquí todo funciona bien, con ese valor realizo una operación cuyo resultado lo reflejo en un span pero el problema es que se va agregando cada resultado uno delante del otro y lo que necesito es que al cambiar el range recalcule y muestre el resultado de acuerdo a su ultima ubicación.

Este es el input type=range y el output donde cargo el valor:

```html
<input oninput="valor_rango.value=Number(rango.value).toLocaleString('es-ES')" type="range" min="15000" max="10000" step="1000" value="25000" id="rango">
 <p>Valor: <output id="valor_rango" for="rango">25000</output></p>
 <p><span id="total"></span></p>
```

Con este scrip realizo la operación:

```html
     $(document).on('change', 'input[type="range"]', function() {

            var valorBase = $('#rango').val();
            var calculo = Math.round((valorBase * 2.3) / 100);
            $('#calculo').after(total);
            total = parseInt(valorBase) + parseInt(calculo);
            $('#total').after(total);

        });
```

De antemano gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo tienes que cambiar `.after` por `.html` asi:

```js
$(document).on('change', 'input[type="range"]', function() {

            var valorBase = $('#rango').val();
            var calculo = Math.round((valorBase * 2.3) / 100);
            $('#calculo').html(total);
            total = parseInt(valorBase) + parseInt(calculo);
            $('#total').html(total);

        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input oninput="valor_rango.value=Number(rango.value).toLocaleString('es-ES')" type="range" min="15000" max="100000" step="1000" value="25000" id="rango">
 <p>Valor: <output id="valor_rango" for="rango">25000</output></p>
 <p><span id="total"></span></p>
```

Comment: Gracias @alanfcm eso es lo que necesitaba